# understanding android ImageView on different size and pixel density devices

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, resolution

I have an image which, on android, I want it to be  110dp in height and to match the parent's width leaving out 10dp margin on the left and the right. Using `ImageView` this is trivial to achieve.

My question is what resolution should I save the image as? I know android has multiple resolution folders for images but I am not sure what each resolution for each folder should be.

overe here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities 
android describe an example on how to scale resolution for the different drawable folders

> if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density
>   screens, all the different sizes should be: ...

**But how do I know where my current image fits best? (mdpi, hdpi ..etc) ?**

apart from the resolution (dpi), the width of the image is not fixed since different devices have different widths. does android take care of this scaling correctly when using `src:=""` ?

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I know where my current image fits best? (mdpi, hdpi ..etc)
>   ?

The answer is, it depends on the layout and for which device you are developing the app. The `dpi` folders will help you make your app look uniform (or different) on various devices.

If you are developing(creating layout, resources) in an `hdpi` device then put the current image in `hdpi` folder. For supporting different devices, scale the size and resolution of the image up/down and put them in correct folder. You can use this scale chart:

```
LDPI - 0.75x
MDPI - Original size // means 1.0x here 
HDPI - 1.5x
XHDPI - 2.0x
XXHDPI - 3x
XXXHDPI - 4.0x
```

Comment: So I should change the resolution according the your table. But should I also change the width and height of the image?  or should these be all the same in all drawable folders?

Comment: Yes. your should. `dpi` folders for `layout` and `drawable` resources are for this purpose.

Comment: You should change the image size as well.

Comment: you said if. Iam developing in an hdpi device then put current image in hdpi folder. Fine, but how di I know that the resolution of current image I designed fits within the hdpi limits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198235/discussion-between-user7331538-and-salmanwahed).

Answer (score 0):

First answer to:  **But how do I know where my current image fits best? (mdpi, hdpi ..etc) ?**

Well the link you shared explains it very well. See screenshots from same link:

[image]

**does android take care of this scaling correctly when using src:="" ?**

If you are using `match_parent` yes. With `wrap_content` it will directly depend on the layout used and other view component configurations.

Comment: is pixels per inch same as DPI? because that is the only way I know what my resolution is (in pixel units)

Comment: Surely not. PPI is for pixels per inch while DPI is for dots per inch. But to give you a understanding of it DPI is dots . But for android those seem same to me. I went through some links and looks like that's the common perception that pixel and dots are same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
resolution | scale index
ldpi       |  0.75 
mdpi       |  1 
hdpi       |  1.5 
xhdpi      |  2
xxhdpi     |  3
xxxhdpi    |  4
```

Also if you use device in landscape mode you could add -sw600dp, -sw720dp etc.
Look at documentation for details https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources